# how to assign random values from array to table cell on a button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to implement the code to create a bingo appliacation where it takes the letters from array on a button click.

How can i assign the array element like array(a,b,c) to those 3X3 table cells randomly on run button click. when i got sequence like abc in a row or diagonal i want increment the count value.

I started but i am unable to implement the code. Can i get any suggestion please.

Here is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function run(){ 
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
     for (var i = 0, row; row = grid.rows[i]; i++){
        row.cells[0].textContent = rand();    
        row.cells[1].textContent = rand();
        row.cells[2].textContent = rand();
     }
score()
    }
    function rand(){
var text = new Array();
var possible = "MCS*";
    return possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
}
function score(){
var Row = document.getElementById("grid");
var Cells = Row.getElementsByTagName("td");
alert(Cells[0].innerText);
alert(Cells[1].innerText);
alert(Cells[2].innerText);
alert(Cells[3].innerText);
alert(Cells[5].innerText);
alert(Cells[6].innerText);
alert(Cells[7].innerText);
alert(Cells[8].innerText);
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form metdod="post">

    <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100"v id="grid">
    <tr>
      <td id="1-1" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="1-2" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="1-3" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="2-1" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="2-2" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="2-3" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td id="3-1" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="3-2" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      <td id="3-3" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      </table>

      <br><br>

      <input type="button" onClick="return run();" value="run">
      </form>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var arr_num = ["1","2","3"];
var match =["123","234","345","567","678","111","222","333","444","555","666"];
function run(){ 
    var counter =0;
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    for (var i = 0, row; row = grid.rows[i]; i++){
        row.cells[0].textContent = arr_num[getRandom()];    
        row.cells[1].textContent = arr_num[getRandom()];
        row.cells[2].textContent = arr_num[getRandom()];
    }
    var a = getMatch();
    for(var i=0;i<getMatch().length; i++){
        if(match.indexOf(a[i]) > -1)
            counter++;
    }
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = counter++;
}
function getMatch(){
    var grid = document.getElementById("grid");
    var match1 = [[]];
    var match_dia =[];
    var temp_dia1 = 0;
    var temp_dia2 = 2;
    var temp_dia3 = 0;
    var temp_dia4 = 2;
    var match_col = [];
    for (var i = 0, row; row = grid.rows[i]; i++){
        match1[match1.length++] = row.cells[0].textContent+row.cells[1].textContent+row.cells[2].textContent;
        match1[match1.length++] = row.cells[2].textContent+row.cells[1].textContent+row.cells[0].textContent;
        if(match_col.length != 0){
            match_col[0] = match_col[0]+row.cells[0].textContent;
            match_col[1] = match_col[1]+row.cells[1].textContent;
            match_col[2] = match_col[2]+row.cells[2].textContent;
            match_col[3] = row.cells[0].textContent+match_col[3];
            match_col[4] = row.cells[1].textContent+match_col[4];
            match_col[5] = row.cells[2].textContent+match_col[5];
        }else{
            match_col[0] = row.cells[0].textContent;
            match_col[1] = row.cells[1].textContent;
            match_col[2] = row.cells[2].textContent;
            match_col[3] = row.cells[0].textContent;
            match_col[4] = row.cells[1].textContent;
            match_col[5] = row.cells[2].textContent;
        }
        if(match_dia.length != 0){
            match_dia[0] = match_dia[0]+row.cells[temp_dia1++].textContent;
            match_dia[1] = match_dia[1]+row.cells[temp_dia2--].textContent;
            match_dia[2] = row.cells[temp_dia3++].textContent+match_dia[2];
            match_dia[3] = row.cells[temp_dia4--].textContent+match_dia[3];
        }else{
            match_dia[0] = row.cells[temp_dia1++].textContent;
            match_dia[1] = row.cells[temp_dia2--].textContent;
            match_dia[2] = row.cells[temp_dia3++].textContent;
            match_dia[3] = row.cells[temp_dia4--].textContent;
        }
    }
    for(var i=0;i<match_col.length;i++){
        match1[match1.length++] = match_col[i];
    }
    match1[match1.length++] = match_dia[0];
    match1[match1.length++] = match_dia[1];
    return match1;
}
function getRandom(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arr_num.length) + 0 ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form metdod="post">

<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="100"v id="grid">
<tr>
    <td id="1-1" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="1-2" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="1-3" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="2-1" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="2-2" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="2-3" height="16" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="3-1" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="3-2" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td id="3-3" height="19" width="20%">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br><br>
<div id="count" name="count"></div>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onClick="return run();" value="run">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Xtroy, Thanks for the reply. When i try to execute that it will not fillout all the cells all the time. Sometimes it is filling sometimes it is not filling. Can you help me out from this.

Comment: didn't check it before.. now its fine

Comment: Hey thats fine @Xtroy. And lastly i need some logic to implement . When i click on run button the cell are filled up right? Now if there is a sequence of letters like 'abc' in a row or horizontal or back horizontal any way i need to increase the count and display count at bottom. you can check i edit my question code also

Comment: test it .. it will give what you want  and also using same login reverse it for column reverse and diagonal reverse

Comment: it is not incrementing the count. Can you check once. I have added the three element to array and match with all the cases. But still the count is showing as zero

Comment: yeah now i tested it for just 3 element ...its working absolutely fine.. if you want to store counter value use hidden field or anything you like

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would assign a value to each cell:

```
for(var row = 1; row <= 3; row++) {
    for(var col = 1; col <= 3; col++ {

        var id = '#'+ row + "-" + col;
        $(id).html(/* put some content here */);
    }
}
```

To assign a random number see [Math.random()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp). If you multiply that value with 10 and round it down, you will get an integer between 0 and 9. Use that value to pick an element from your array.

**Edit**

So if you have an array like `letters = [ "A", "B", "CD", "asum", 12, "whatsoever" ]`and a random number `n` then `letters[n]` will give you the array element with index `n`. For `n == 2`: `letters[n] == "CD"`

Comment: hi @Tekay
 but i need that cells to be filled with random values from array
like array('a','b','c')

Answer (score 0):

Well this is NOT bingo but your "assign random letter a,b,c to a space in a grid" can be satisfied by:

```
var bingocol = ["a", "b", "c"];
/**
 * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
 * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
 */
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
$('#runbingo').on("click", function() {
  var nextcolindex = getRandomIntInclusive(0, 2);
  var nextletterindex = getRandomIntInclusive(0, 2);
  var nextrow =  getRandomIntInclusive(0, 2);
  $('#grid').find('tr').eq(nextrow).find('td').eq(nextcolindex).html(bingocol[nextletterindex]);
});
```

NOW if you really want to emulate BINGO where the column varies and the NUMBERS in the column vary by a given sequence that is a different problem; note that you would then need to have one algorithm to assign the player cards and another to pick random values from a list for the "game" card both of which would need to consider the range and previously filled values to exclude duplicates - doable but an entirely different problem.

Here is the code above in action: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/tjd7j3oh/